# How to update Portal for ArcGIS system properties using ArcGIS API for Python

Tags: arcgis-portal, arcgis-python-api

I'd like to update the Portal system properties using the Python API. The [documentation](https://esri.github.io/arcgis-python-api/apidoc/html/arcgis.gis.admin.html#arcgis.gis.admin.System.properties) seems to indicate that it can be done. However, making an assignment to System.properties doesn't appear to udpate the system properties.

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS

gis = GIS(gis_base_url, user, password)
system_properties = gis.admin.system.properties
system_properties['privatePortalURL'] = system_properties['WebContextURL']
gis.admin.system.properties = system_properties
```

So, is there a way to update the Portal's system properties in a way other than what's documented?

Comment: What does the above return in the console?  Are you using a user with POrtal Admin privileges?

Comment: Nothing, and yes.